# Apply top filters in batch mode

Tags: linux, centos-7

I can apply the my desired filters interactive mode (by pressing o). Is there a way to get these in batch mode.

I am using procps-ng version 3.3.10.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), the `-p` command line option can be used to restrict which processes `top` reads. It does not appear to allow filtering exactly as in interactive mode, but you can achieve essentially the same result by examining the output of `ps`.

Example, taking only processes with more than three threads:

```
$ ps -eLf | awk '$6 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { if ($6 > 3) { print $2; } }' | sort -u
```

On my computer, this prints out a list of all the relevant processes, one on each line. `ps` generates the list of process details, the `awk` command filters them, and `sort` just removes duplicates.

For your use, check which columns of `ps` you are going to need. On my computer, the number of threads ("NLWP") is the sixth column (`$6`), and the process id ("PID") is the second column (`$2`). Adjust these in the `awk` command as necessary to match the filter you need. Notice that `$6` appears twice: first to make sure it is a number and not the header, and the second time to make sure it is more than 3.

After running this command, the process ids must be given to `top`. Bash and probably other shells allow passing the output of a program as arguments to another program, so the final command could be

```
$ top $(ps -eLf | awk '$6 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { if ($6 > 3) { print "-p"$2; } }' | sort -u) ... And other options
```

`"-p"` was added to make the output work with `top`. Adjust this command to fit your filter and shell as necessary, drop it into your batch, and it should work.

*Note: Adding more filters will probably require learning awk. It's not too hard.*